# python: quick fix for a list of two lists into one list

Tags: python

Trying to flatten a list of lists into one list of unique values:

`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8]]` into `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` where the first list might contain N number of lists.

Comment: Do you mean that a sublist might *itself* contain lists? If so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score -1):

You could try it like this:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]

nxtList = []
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        nxtList.append(j)
```

This won't guarantee that your values are unique, but if you know ahead of time that the list (a) always contains unique values then it won't be a problem.